# using "ing" after "to" see the below paragraph "sign in to using their identities"

Tags: grammar

What is the Microsoft identity platform?

The Microsoft identity platform helps you build applications your users and ***customers can sign in to using their Microsoft identities*** or social accounts, and provide authorized access to your own APIs or Microsoft APIs like Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it this way:

> The Microsoft identity platform  / helps you build applications / your users and customers can sign in to / using their Microsoft identities or social accounts, / and provide authorized access to your own APIs or Microsoft APIs / like Microsoft Graph.

where "using their Microsoft identities or social accounts," is how you log in to those accounts.

"sign in to" refers to the action of signing in or logging in to some website or web application.

Comment: "sign in to" them " using their Microsoft identities or social accounts". is that how should I read it.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.